# Query to get the previous element related to the id in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables. One is Device and the other is POS in a many to many relationship. What I need is to get all the devices from the POS id I'm seeking but get the previous device, not the latest one. I wanna use it as a function on my model to have easy access to that element on Device.

```
Device
--------
- id
- other elements 
- pos_id
- function to get the previous device for the above pos_id

POS
--------
- id
- other stuff

Devices_pos
----------
- device_id
- pos_id
```

I know I can access $pos->devices and get all the elements.

I've tried:

```
public function scopePrev_dev_pos()
    {
        if ($this->pos_id > 0){
            $pos = Pos::find($this->pos_id);
            return $pos->devices->where('device_id', '<', $this->id)->max('device_id');
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

All it gives me is an Eloquent Builder that apparently doesn't have anything inside.

The query is supposed to be something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(device_id) FROM devices_pos
WHERE pos_id = 7
AND device_id < 7035;
```

... but using Eloquent. ids are only an example.

---

EDIT: Ended up using an accessor:

```
public function getPreviousDeviceAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->pos_id > 0){
            $pos = Pos::find($this->pos_id);
            $prev = DB::table('devices_pos')->where('device_id', '<', $this->id)
                    ->where('pos_id', $this->pos_id)
                    ->max('device_id');
            $device = Device::find($prev);
            return $device;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I leave the question open because I'm using the facade and not Eloquent but it's a good workaround. A local scope was not useful for my issue (if you need to test for null it won't work).

Comment: See Updated answer  used `newPivot()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this it must be work

`$pos->devices()->newPivot()->where([
        ['device_id', '<', $this->id],
        ['pos_id','=', $this->pos_id]
    ])->max('device_id');`

Or you can use

```
DevicePos::where([
    ['device_id', '<', $this->id],
    ['pos_id','=', $this->pos_id]
])->max('device_id');
```

see related https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates

Example with `DB` facade

```
DB::table('devices_pos')->where([
        ['device_id', '<', $this->id],
        ['pos_id','=', $this->pos_id]
    ])->max('device_id');
```

Comment: The problem is when I make the query on raw SQL it works but this way I just get NULL.

Comment: Also check `$this->pos_id` value? what is it??

Comment: The value of pos_id is 7

Comment: $this->id  value ??

Comment: For test first use Device::max('device_id');

Comment: then Device::where(''device_id', '<', 7000)->max('device_id');

Comment: $this->id = 7035. Remember it's a many to many relationship table.

Comment: show `$pos->devices->where('device_id', '<', $this->id)->toSql()`; result

Comment: Try `$pos->devices()->newPivot()->toSql()` This must be like this `SELECT * FROM devices_pos`. And then you can add where condition for future use for example `$pos->devices()->newPivot() ->where('device_id', '<', $this->id)->get()`